# About the developing of the ipad applications

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I've started working on an iPad application, my first application is "Hello World",
for that I have the following code in the MasterViewController.h

---

```
#import    @class DetailViewController;     
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController   
{ DetailViewController *detailViewController;   
       NSArray * fruits;   
}     
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DetailViewController *detailViewController;   
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *fruits;    
@end
```

---

And in MasterViewController.m

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
      [super viewDidLoad]; self.fruits =   
      [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]   
      pathForResource:@"fruits" ofType:@"plist"]] retain];   
}
```

---

but it is not working.

Comment: What is not working? Is it compiling? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: yuuup..when i build and run the the code then during compilation it gives some exception..

Comment: What is not working? are you getting any errors?

Comment: What's the exception? Do you have the fruits.plist file added and formatted correctly?

Comment: @Lol-jim :- yuuup..when i build and run the the code then during compilation it gives some exception..

Comment: @tomasmcguinness:-yaaa, i have fruits.plist file added and formatted correctly...

Comment: @tomasmcguinnes:- m sorry i forgot to give you the exception, it gives"Uncaught exception thrown - ControlledAccessException":(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two observations, you shouldn't be retaining the array that you are fetching (in the viewDidLoad method). Your property is taking care of that.

Your property for fruits is also defined as an NSMutableArray, however the instance-variable is an NSArray - and you are also loading the plist as an NSArray. Is this what the compiler is complaining about?